# How Can I extract the .dat file(contain image) using java API

Tags: java, apache-poi

if  i using [HMEFContentsExtractor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hmef/extractor/HMEFContentsExtractor.html) in POI jar, it can extract html only it is not able extract the image content form winmail.dat(attchment mail sent from oulook), is there any jar file to do this & explain how to use that.

```
HMEFContentsExtractor ext = new HMEFContentsExtractor(new File(winmailFilename));
File dir = new File(directoryName);
File rtf = new File(dir, "message.rtf");
if(! dir.exists()) {
     throw new FileNotFoundException("Output directory "+dir.getName()+" not found");   
}
HMEFMessage msg = new HMEFMessage(new FileInputStream(winmailFilename));
msg.getAttachments();ext.extractMessageBody(rtf);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help get an answer to this question, you haven't given any error messages or indicated where you are stuck.

Comment: Hi, could you describe what `winmail.dat` file is ? and when you state you're not able to extract the image, what image you're referring to and also is there any error stacktrace from your application?

Comment: Why can't you extract it? What isn't working? What exceptions do you get?